# react:<Container fluid="true"> takes more than 100% width

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am try to give full width to my container by passing props fluid="true" but it takes more than 100% width.
This is my code

```
          <Container fluid="true" style={{backgroundColor:'#0086FF'}}>
            <Row >
                <Col>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                   <div>
                       <p>This is my division</p>
                   </div>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
```

Comment: reset the default margins and paddings.

Comment: actually <Row> was taking more than 100% width then i reset default margin and padding of Row and its working..thank you @jai